# How to set new Map location onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, google-maps-android-api-2

What's the wrong with my code? . Why the map show with the default location when i press the button ?

Here's my setOnClickListener

```
    holder.mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v ) {
            //if you need position, just use recycleViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "OMG! The position is still here and is: "+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:35.2137,31.7683");
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapsActivity.class );
            intent.putExtra("location",uri);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And here's my Map activity:

```
   @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Comment: You need to provide more information in your post. It is impossible for us to know why your `MapsActivity` is not displaying the selected location without you showing us your `MapsActivity`  code.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't go to the new location .i'll edit the post.
@Barns

Comment: The map never shows the new coordinates because you never change them--you are still using the `LatLng` values for "sydney"

Comment: Could you please tell me how can change the values when i click the button ?@Barns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onClick` method get the latitude and longitude from your list (I have hard coded them here for an example, only).

```
public void onClick(View v ) {
    double lat = 35.2137;
    double lng = 31.7683;
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapsActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
    intent.putExtra("lng",lng);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your `MapsActivity` add the instance variable:

```
private LatLng mLatLng;
```

Now in your `onCreate` method of your `MapsActivity` do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", -34);
double lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", 151);

mLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Please note that -34 and 151 are default values. You can select any coordinates you prefer.

Now you can use the new coordinates in your `onMapReady` method set this value:

`mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));`